# How can starting time of a Spark application on a YARN cluster be shorten?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm managing a system that submits a Spark application to a YARN cluster in a client mode. It takes about 30 seconds for a submitted Spark application to turn to be ready on a YARN cluster and it seems a bit slow for me.

Are there any ways for shortening starting time of a Spark application on a YARN cluster in a client mode?

Here are specs of my environment:
- Spark version: 2.1.1 (the actual version is 2.1.1.2.6.2.0-205 which is provided by Hortonworks)
- YARN version: 2.7.3 (the actual version is 2.7.3.2.6.2.0-205 which is provided by Hortonworks)
- Number of RM: 2 (HA)
- Number of NM: 300

Here is the sample code and result for checking starting time of a Spark application:

```
$ /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-shell -v --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4g --conf spark.default.parallelism=180 --conf spark.executor.cores=6 --conf spark.executor.instances=30 --conf spark.executor.memory=6g --conf spark.yarn.am.cores=4 --conf spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads=30 --conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/R/lib/sparkr.zip#sparkr --conf spark.yarn.dist.files=/etc/spark2/conf/hive-site.xml --proxy-user xxxx

Using properties file: /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/spark-defaults.conf
Adding default property: spark.history.kerberos.keytab=/etc/security/keytabs/spark.headless.keytab
Adding default property: spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs:///spark2-history/
Adding default property: spark.eventLog.enabled=true
Adding default property: spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
Adding default property: spark.yarn.queue=default
Adding default property: spark.yarn.historyServer.address=xxxx
Adding default property: spark.history.kerberos.principal=xxxx@xxxx
Adding default property: spark.history.provider=org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
Adding default property: spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
Adding default property: spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs:///spark2-history/
Adding default property: spark.history.ui.port=18081
Adding default property: spark.history.kerberos.enabled=true
Parsed arguments:
  master                  yarn
  deployMode              client
  executorMemory          6g
  executorCores           6
  totalExecutorCores      null
  propertiesFile          /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  driverMemory            4g
  driverCores             null
  driverExtraClassPath    null
  driverExtraLibraryPath  /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
  driverExtraJavaOptions  null
  supervise               false
  queue                   null
  numExecutors            30
  files                   null
  pyFiles                 null
  archives                null
  mainClass               org.apache.spark.repl.Main
  primaryResource         spark-shell
  name                    Spark shell
  childArgs               []
  jars                    null
  packages                null
  packagesExclusions      null
  repositories            null
  verbose                 true

Spark properties used, including those specified through
 --conf and those from the properties file /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/spark-defaults.conf:
  (spark.history.kerberos.enabled,true)
  (spark.yarn.queue,default)
  (spark.default.parallelism,180)
  (spark.executor.extraLibraryPath,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64)
  (spark.history.kerberos.principal,xxxx@xxxx)
  (spark.executor.memory,6g)
  (spark.driver.memory,4g)
  (spark.driver.extraLibraryPath,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64)
  (spark.executor.instances,30)
  (spark.yarn.historyServer.address,xxxx)
  (spark.eventLog.enabled,true)
  (spark.yarn.dist.files,/etc/spark2/conf/hive-site.xml)
  (spark.history.ui.port,18081)
  (spark.history.provider,org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider)
  (spark.history.fs.logDirectory,hdfs:///spark2-history/)
  (spark.yarn.am.cores,4)
  (spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads,30)
  (spark.history.kerberos.keytab,/etc/security/keytabs/spark.headless.keytab)
  (spark.yarn.dist.archives,/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/R/lib/sparkr.zip#sparkr)
  (spark.eventLog.dir,hdfs:///spark2-history/)
  (spark.executor.cores,6)


Main class:
org.apache.spark.repl.Main
Arguments:

System properties:
(spark.yarn.queue,default)
(spark.history.kerberos.enabled,true)
(spark.default.parallelism,180)
(spark.executor.extraLibraryPath,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64)
(spark.history.kerberos.principal,xxxx@xxxx)
(spark.driver.memory,4g)
(spark.executor.memory,6g)
(spark.executor.instances,30)
(spark.driver.extraLibraryPath,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64)
(spark.yarn.historyServer.address,xxxx)
(spark.eventLog.enabled,true)
(spark.yarn.dist.files,file:/etc/spark2/conf/hive-site.xml)
(spark.history.ui.port,18081)
(SPARK_SUBMIT,true)
(spark.history.provider,org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider)
(spark.app.name,Spark shell)
(spark.history.fs.logDirectory,hdfs:///spark2-history/)
(spark.yarn.am.cores,4)
(spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads,30)
(spark.jars,)
(spark.history.kerberos.keytab,/etc/security/keytabs/spark.headless.keytab)
(spark.submit.deployMode,client)
(spark.yarn.dist.archives,file:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/R/lib/sparkr.zip#sparkr)
(spark.eventLog.dir,hdfs:///spark2-history/)
(spark.master,yarn)
(spark.executor.cores,6)
Classpath elements:



Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://xxxx:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1519898793082_6925).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1.2.6.2.0-205
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Thanks.